# Spring Security OAuth 2 JWKS Resource Server (Legacy) has NULL Principal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I need to setup a legacy Spring-Boot 1.5 project to act as a OAuth2 Resource Server using the exposed JWKS to validate all the incoming JWTs at each request.

The links and articles that I have followed/checked are:

- https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-jws-jwk
- [Spring Security OAuth with JWK Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624861/spring-security-oauth-with-jwk-example)

I have the following dependencies in my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>project</groupId>
<artifactId>project-resource</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Project Resource</name>
<description>Project Resource</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html-->
    <!--https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#resource-server-configuration-->
    <!--https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/resource-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I configured it to act as a Resource Server and use the JWKS uri in the `application.yml`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwk:
        key-set-uri: http://sso.server/.well-known/jwks.json
```

The main class is as simple as:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class ProjectResourceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectResourceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In order to use the APIs from another domain I also had to provide this `CorsFilter`,
since the simple httpSecurity.cors() didn't work.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Value("${custom.cors.allowOrigin:*}")
    private String allowOrigin;

    @Value("${custom.cors.allowMethods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS}")
    private String allowMethods;

    @Value("${custom.cors.allowHeaders:Content-Type,Authorization}")
    private String allowHeaders;

    @Value("${custom.cors.allowCredentials:true}")
    private String allowCredentials;

    @Value("${custom.cors.maxAge:3600}")
    private String maxAge;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOrigin);

        if (HttpMethod.OPTIONS.matches(request.getMethod())) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", allowMethods);
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", allowHeaders);
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", allowCredentials);
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", maxAge);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

The authorization is working fine, meaning that the token is validated correctly with the JWKS,
however the Principal is always null.

e.g.:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
public class PrincipalController {

    @GetMapping("/principal")
    public Principal getPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong or missing? In addition I would also like to have a custom object as Principal if possible.
Does the Rosource Server require to also have info about the client in order to provide the Principal? as found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is adding a `@Bean` of type [UserInfoTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/UserInfoTokenServices.html) as explained below.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650255/8737144
- [Spring OAuth2 ResourceServer external AuthorizationServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033326/spring-oauth2-resourceserver-external-authorizationserver/44195050)

Such `@Bean` can be further customized with custom [Principal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/PrincipalExtractor.html) & [Authorities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/AuthoritiesExtractor.html) extractors.